# Assets (images, JS and CSS) not getting served after upgrading to Rails 4.2.0 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error that I am getting is

"No route matches [GET]...."

I have already tried doing following things in environments/production.rb

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']
```

PS : I am using Apache2 for hosting my rails app

Comment: Your answer did not solve my problem but it helped put me in right direction, hence the up vote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the issue

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

I did not have and environment variable and it was causing an issue.

For people who land upon this question

Answer (score 1):

I've had more issues upgrading from rails 4.1 to rails 4.2 then I've had upgrading between any other version of rails ever. I use nginx, but go ahead and please try the following:

- prefix the following commands with RAILS_ENV=production and run `rake tmp:clear`, `rake asset:clean` and `rake asset:precompile`
- `config.assets.compile = false`
- `config.serve_static_files = false`

Comment: I will give this a try and update here back. Thanks for the answer.